# Python terminal based code is raising an : [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, terminal, python-os

## Hi there is a weird problem when i use terminal based stuff in Python

**(I use Windows with VS Code)**

My code looks like this

```
import os
os.system('C:/Users/.../Downloads/.../lib/python3.9/venv/scripts/nt')
```

But there is a **very** weird error:

```
[Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

The error is confusing ,before every terminal based code could work fine but now it's always showing that or sometimes this:

```
>>Why
>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using double quotes and also providing the full path as an argument to the  function call. e.g.

```
import os
os.system("C:/path/to/script/being/executed")
```

Comment: Thanks but i had a problem in file name (that is not important) i placed this ' in my file name ,I solved it.